# How to execute a function which has both out parameter and return value to get the result both in sql developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, stored-functions, ref-cursor

```
create or replace FUNCTION RETURN_AP_ORDER_CUR (count_product OUT NOCOPY SYS_REFCURSOR)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR 
AS
APP_RECORDSET SYS_REFCURSOR;
i AP_ORDER%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN 

OPEN APP_RECORDSET FOR 
SELECT ORDER_ID,REGEXP_REPLACE(PRODUCT_NAME, '^\s', '') PRODUCT_NAME
   FROM
        (
         SELECT a.ORDER_ID, b.COLUMN_VALUE as PRODUCT_NAME
         FROM (SELECT ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_NAME FROM AP_ORDER) a 
         NATURAL JOIN TABLE(FNC_COL2ROW(PRODUCT_NAME)) b 
        );

RETURN APP_RECORDSET;

LOOP
 FETCH APP_RECORDSET INTO i;
EXIT WHEN APP_RECORDSET%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.ORDER_ID||' '||i.PRODUCT_NAME);
INSERT INTO AP_ORDER_SPLIT (ORDER_ID,PRODUCT_NAME) VALUES (i.ORDER_ID,i.PRODUCT_NAME);
COMMIT;
END LOOP;
close APP_RECORDSET;

OPEN count_product FOR Select ORDER_ID,COUNT(1) from AP_ORDER_SPLIT group by ORDER_ID;
   
    EXCEPTION
WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
 dbms_output.put_line('**Error** Several Values'); -- do something meaningful here 
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
 dbms_output.put_line('There is no data in variable');
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Error code ' || SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
   END RETURN_AP_ORDER_CUR;
```

using bind variable how I can get the result in SQL developer for both out parameter and return value.

Please share me one anonymous block
kindly suggest some ways

- Store comma separated value to ref-cursor
- used function inside sql statement to get separated value
- Fetching count data to out parameter

Answer (score 0):

Once function reaches the `RETURN` statement, nothing else is being executed so all that code (loop, fetch, etc.) is "skipped".

A simplified which shows *how* to do it:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_rc out nocopy sys_refcursor)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open par_rc for select * from dept;
  7
  8    open l_rc for select empno, ename, job, sal from emp
  9                  where deptno = 10;
 10
 11    return l_rc;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.
```

Call such a function:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_out sys_refcursor;  -- will hold function's OUT parameter
  3    l_ret sys_refcursor;  -- will hold function's RETURN value
  4  begin
  5    l_ret := f_test(l_out);
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```